# Got stuck on logic of a given array

Tags: kotlin

I have this code:

```
val string = "<p></p>this<p></p>"
val arrs = listOf("<p data-id=\"1\"></p>", "<p data-id=\"2\"></p>")
var replacedString = ""
arrs.forEach {
    val pTag = "<p></p>"
    replacedString = string.replace(pTag, it) // <-- I know this is the culprit, but I got stuck. don't know what to do anymore
}
println(replacedString)
```

It should show `<p data-id="1"></p>this<p data-id="2"></p>` , but it shows
`<p data-id="2"></p>this<p data-id="2"></p>` instead

notice the `data-id` value is incrementing in accordance to the list

The main problem is that the `string` variable and the `listOf` will be dynamic.

for example:

```
val string = "<p></p>this<p></p>that<p></p>"
val arrs = listOf("<p data-id=\"1\"></p>", "<p data-id=\"2\"></p>", "<p data-id=\"3\"></p>")
```

or

```
val string = "<p></p>this<p></p><p></p>that"
val arrs = listOf("<p data-id=\"1\"></p>", "<p data-id=\"2\"></p>", "<p data-id=\"3\"></p>")
```

so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues,

1. `.replace` will replace **all** occurences in the string. This is likely what you don't want. Maybe you need to use `replaceFirst`
2. `replacedString` is overwritten in every pass of the `forEach`. Therefore, it will only have the value of the last iteration, which is result of what you observe. Ideally use a `StringBuilder` here and append the `replaceString` result on every pass.

So in effect,

```
var replacedString = string 
arrs.forEach {
    val pTag = "<p></p>"
    replacedString = replacedString.replaceFirst(pTag, it))
} 
println(replacedString)
```

Hope that gets you moving along

Comment: would you show me the complete pseudocode on that?

Comment: it's close. it shows me `<p data-id="1"></p>this<p></p><p data-id="2"></p>this<p></p>` tho which is unexpected

Comment: ah, i see the problem. Have updated accordingly. There are more efficient ways to do this, and this will work for now

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(replacePtag("<p></p>this<p></p><p></p>that"))
    //<p data-id=1></p>this<p data-id=2></p><p data-id=3></p>that
    println(replacePtag("<p></p>this<p></p>"))
    //<p data-id=1></p>this<p data-id=2></p>
}

fun replacePtag(inputHtml: String): String {
    val tag = "<p></p>"
    fun p(id: Int): String = "<p data-id=$id></p>"
    var input = inputHtml
    var currentId = 1
    var tmp = input.replaceFirst(tag, p(currentId))
    currentId++
    while (tmp != input) {
        input = tmp
        tmp = tmp.replaceFirst(tag, p(currentId))
        currentId++
    }
    return input
}
```